# Show serializer attribute only for current user and certain role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I need the auth_token attribute to only be outputted for the current authenticated user.

My User controller has

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :json

  def show
    authorize User
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
...
```

The serializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :auth_token
  has_one :role
```

The http request goes something like:
GET http://api.domain.com/users/1
With Headers: Accept, Content-Type and Authorization
(Authorization is the auth_token).

What's returned is:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user1@domain.com",
    "created_at": "2015-12-01T07:36:55.276Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-12-01T07:36:55.276Z",
    "auth_token": "8xxoZjZyx313cx2poabz",
    "role": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "admin",
      "created_at": "2015-12-01T07:36:55.190Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-12-01T07:36:55.190Z"
    }
  }
}
```

**I only want `auth_token` to be shown if the user that it belongs to requests it or a user with the `super` role requests it. I have a method in my user model that can check for a role like `has_role? :super`.**

In the serializer I've tried this but it was really just a shot in the dark. I have no idea how to accomplish this:

```
...
def filter(keys)
  if scope.auth_token == :auth_token
    keys
  else
    keys - [:auth_token]
  end
end
```

#### Edit

Using active_model_serializer version 0.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Saw [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/8e1245a5b26e1a80dae8e66fa06336f4ca8a5cba/lib/active_model/serializer/collection_serializer.rb#L10-L23) in the source and something clicked in my head.

Changing the `filter` method above to the following gave me the desired results.

```
  def filter(keys)
    if (scope == object) or scope.has_role?(:super)
      keys
    else
      keys - [:auth_token]
    end
  end
```

Hope this helps anyone else using version 0.9.x

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer, even though `:auth_token` is a field, you should be able to overwrite it with a method of the same name.

So:

```rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :auth_token
  has_one :role

  def auth_token
    object.auth_token == scope.auth_token || scope.has_role?(:super) ? object.auth_token : nil
  end
end
```